# Create new column showing count of missing values

Tags: python, pandas

Below is script for a simplified version of the df in question:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
               'id'            : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
               'feature'       : ['cd_player', 'sat_nav', 'sub_woofer', 'usb_port','cd_player', 'sat_nav', 'sub_woofer', 'usb_port','cd_player', 'sat_nav', 'sub_woofer', 'usb_port'],
               'feature_value' : [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
                 })
df

    id  feature     feature_value
0   1   cd_player   1
1   1   sat_nav     1
2   1   sub_woofer  1
3   1   usb_port    0
4   2   cd_player   1
5   2   sat_nav     0
6   2   sub_woofer  0
7   2   usb_port    1
8   3   cd_player   1
9   3   sat_nav     1
10  3   sub_woofer  1
11  3   usb_port    0
```

What I would like to do, is create a new column which counts the number of `0` values for each feature as per the df below.

INTENDED DF:

```
    id  feature     feature_value   no_value_count
0   1   cd_player   1               0
1   1   sat_nav     1               1
2   1   sub_woofer  1               1
3   1   usb_port    0               2
4   2   cd_player   1               0
5   2   sat_nav     0               1
6   2   sub_woofer  0               1
7   2   usb_port    1               2
8   3   cd_player   1               0
9   3   sat_nav     1               1
10  3   sub_woofer  1               1
11  3   usb_port    0               2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df["count"] = df["id"].nunique() - df.groupby("feature")["feature_value"].transform("sum")

print (df)

    id     feature  feature_value  count
0    1   cd_player              1      0
1    1     sat_nav              1      1
2    1  sub_woofer              1      1
3    1    usb_port              0      2
4    2   cd_player              1      0
5    2     sat_nav              0      1
6    2  sub_woofer              0      1
7    2    usb_port              1      2
8    3   cd_player              1      0
9    3     sat_nav              1      1
10   3  sub_woofer              1      1
11   3    usb_port              0      2
```

Comment: I'm going with this solution. Because it takes id into consideration, I have potential missing features for each id covered. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can `map` the column feature with the result of `groupby.sum` by feature where the column feature_value is equal (`eq`) to 0.

```
df['no_value_count'] = df['feature'].map(df['feature_value'].eq(0)
                                           .groupby(df['feature']).sum())
print(df)
    id     feature  feature_value  no_value_count
0    1   cd_player              1               0
1    1     sat_nav              1               1
2    1  sub_woofer              1               1
3    1    usb_port              0               2
4    1   cd_player              1               0
5    2     sat_nav              0               1
6    2  sub_woofer              0               1
7    2    usb_port              1               2
8    2   cd_player              1               0
9    2     sat_nav              1               1
10   3  sub_woofer              1               1
11   3    usb_port              0               2
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you can try:

```
df['feature_value'].eq(0).groupby(df['feature']).transform('sum')
```

---

```
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     0.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     2.0
8     0.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    2.0
```